# PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR: could not open extension control file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, osx-yosemite

After upgrading Postgres i am getting the following error when i try to migrate the database.

```
enable_extension(:postgis)
  SQL (17.2ms)  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "postgis"
/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
/Users/harshamv/Sites/clink/db/migrate/20150812164615_enable_postgis.rb:3:in `change'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Not sure where to get started. Most other questions seem to related to Linux and when i tried to create the symlink also it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried `brew install postgis`?

Comment: Looks like PostGIS needs reinstalling, yeah. For some reason Homebrew seems to install to a directory including the minor version like /9.4.5/ which will break things on every minor update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS, installing postgis worked for me using below command:

```
brew install postgis
```

For Ubuntu, below command works:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect available postgresql postgis versions

```
sudo apt-cache search postgis
```

Install

```
sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts
```

Switch postgres user

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Create a database and then connect it. After this run the command for postgis extension activation

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Later you can check and verify it by

```
SELECT PostGIS_version();
```